# How to register command for right click - Discord.JS V14

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create a delete command where when you right click on a message, it will show under apps "Delete Message" from my bot. For example, Atlas has a set reminder (which seems useless) function under apps [[image.]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi7b7.png) I would like to create this as a **guild command**. Also, I would like to know how to use the interaction create with this right-click-context-menu function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To register these commands, you need to set the `type` of the `ApplicationCommand` to `1` (or `ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput`). See the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ApplicationCommand?scrollTo=type).

Everything else should stay the same except the `type`. You can register these commands the usual way, which is documented in the guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html#guild-commands)

Here's a snippet:

```js
// token should be your bot's token
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            // commands should be an array of ApplicationCommands
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you wanted a `guild command`, I believe the [current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73742004/22541482) is outdated. I would leave a comment if I had enough rep, but I can't, so here is my correction. The `type` of `ApplicationCommand` should not be `ChatInput`, but rather, `Message`.

```js
const messageContextMenu = new ContextMenuCommandBuilder()
  .setName('Message Command')
  .setType(disc.ApplicationCommandType.Message);
```

You can then call `toJSON()` on `messageContextMenu`, which you can push to a `commands` array, and then register as you normally would with a slash command.